# Spinner Scroll Selected Value

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

RecyclerView not saving Spinner values.

I have tried available examples all on stackoverflow, I could not find a working solution.

Please find my code of my RecyclerView Below:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.spinnerlist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            valueselected.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

            valueselected.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    valueselected.setSelection(i, true);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
            valueselected.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

            valueselected.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Once scrolled, the selected value of the spinner needs to remain.

Comment: You wan't to get selected value/position  in spinner?

Comment: Good Day Haresh, when I select the value in the spinner and I scroll up and down within the recyclerview, the selection that I made disappears and revert back to the no value selected. - I need to keep the selection when scrolling. Thank You

Comment: ok, I help you, please past your whole activity and adapter class code

Comment: It doesnt stays selected because the spinner is UI but your data has not been updated. When the user selects the spinner update the recyclerview data to reflect the selection and then call notifydatasetchabge